# Subconsultas Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

Tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas y otras mas.
id id_cliente id_pieza create_at
Lo que necesito obtener es una consulta que me de los últimos dos registros mas actuales por fecha de cada pieza de cada cliente. Se me complico bastante y no se como hacerlo.

```
id id_cliente id_pieza    pieza            create_at
1      2          1   GUIA DE VASTAGO   2019-04-26 11:16:22
2      2          1   GUIA DE VASTAGO   2019-04-25 11:31:35
3      2          1   GUIA DE VASTAGO   2019-04-24 11:38:23
4      2          2   ANILLO SEPARADOR  2019-04-26 11:41:31
5      2          2   ANILLO SEPARADOR  2019-04-25 11:43:14
6      2          2   ANILLO SEPARADOR  2019-04-24 10:54:18
7      3          1   PERNO INFERIOR    2019-04-26 11:41:31
8      3          1   PERNO INFERIOR    2019-04-25 11:43:14
9      3          1   PERNO INFERIOR    2019-04-24 10:54:18
```

O sea por ejemplo ahi deberia obtener los ultimos dos mas actuales de la pieza 1 del cliente 2, los ultimos dos mas actuales de la pieza 2 del cliente 2, los ultimos dos mas actuales  de la pieza 1 del cliente 3 y asi sucesivamente.
Gracias.

Esto es lo que me gustaría obtener. Espero que se entienda.

```
   id id_cliente id_pieza      pieza               create_at
    1      2          1   GUIA DE VASTAGO    2019-04-26 11:16:22
    2      2          1   GUIA DE VASTAGO    2019-04-25 11:31:35
    4      2          2   ANILLO SEPARADOR   2019-04-26 11:41:31
    5      2          2   ANILLO SEPARADOR   2019-04-25 11:43:14
    7      3          1   PERNO INFERIOR     2019-04-26 11:41:31
    8      3          1   PERNO INFERIOR     2019-04-25 11:43:14
```

Comment: Nos muestras lo que lloevas hecho por favor

Comment: He probado hacer la consulta pero no logro obtener lo que quiero. No las he guardado ya que no funcionaban. Aclaro que no tengo mysql 8 porq he visto algunas cosas en internet que utilizan funciones que mi mysql no tiene.

Comment: podrías por favor editar y colocar una muestra de los datos que esperas obtener

Comment: Ahi lo edite, le agregue el nombre de la pieza para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque podría parecer, no es una consulta tan sencilla, pero hay varias técnicas para abordarla.
Una forma *"fancy"* de conseguir lo que pides es usando una subconsulta para contar los valores mayores de `create_at` de la tabla (`a`) comparándolos con los valores de la misma tabla pero con otro `alias` (`b`)

```
SELECT a.id, a.id_cliente, a.id_pieza, a.pieza, a.create_at 
FROM NOMBRE_DE_LA_TABLA AS a 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NOMBRE_DE_LA_TABLA as b 
    WHERE b.pieza=a.pieza AND b.create_at >= a.create_at 
) <= 2 ORDER BY id ASC
```

### Otras referencias

Si estás usando MySQL v8.x, puedes usar funciones como [RANK() y DENSE_RANK()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198697/how-to-get-latest-2-records-of-each-group) que crean un ranking a partir de un set de datos

Ejemplos (en inglés) para verlo en funcionamiento
[How to get latest 2 records of each group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198697/how-to-get-latest-2-records-of-each-group) y también [Get the rank of a user in a score table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table)

Otra forma de hacerlo es usando variables internas como se puede observar en este otro ejemplo (en inglés) [MySQL Query get the last N rows per Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716152/mysql-query-get-the-last-n-rows-per-group)

Comment: La verdad que si, no me pareció nada fácil jaja. Recién ahora lo pude probar, funciona perfecto, te agradezco mucho!.